# Nest - Nest can't resolve dependencies

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nest, nestjs-config

I have a very simple `CryptoModule` that looks like this:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { CryptoService } from './crypto.service';

@Module({
  providers: [CryptoService],
  exports: [CryptoService],
})
export class CryptoModule {}
```

Now the service `CryptoService` is using an environment variable to set the secret key, and for that I use Nest Config package.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import Cryptr from 'cryptr';

@Injectable()
export class CryptoService {
  constructor(private readonly config: ConfigService, private cryptr: Cryptr) {
    this.cryptr = new Cryptr(this.config.get('CRYPTO_SECRET'));
  }

  encrypt = this.cryptr.encrypt;
  decrypt = this.cryptr.decrypt;
}
```

The ConfigModule is imported in `app.module` like so:

```
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: !ENV ? '.env' : `.env.${ENV}`,
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
```

The thing is I keep getting the following error:

> "Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CryptoService
> (ConfigService, ?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at
> index [1] is available in the CryptoModule context.\n"

But since the `ConfigModule` is global I don't think it has to be added to the imports of the crypto module? I also tried doing that by the way and still the same error message... Am I missing something?

The only place where I use this module at the moment is here:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { UserController } from './user.controller';
import { CryptoModule } from '../crypto/crypto.module';

@Module({
  imports: [CryptoModule],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

And of course in the service than I import the `CryptoService`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you added `private cryptr: Cryptr` in the constructor. Nest is trying to resolve this but there is no module `Cryptr`.

Try removing it from the constructor and add a variable `cryptr` instead.

```js
cryptr: Cryptr

constructor(private readonly config: ConfigService){ /* ... */
```

Comment: This and enabling `"esModuleInterop": true` in `tsconfig.json` fixes the problem! Maybe add this to your answer as well for future references?